# How to merge multiple signal and stop on first next but not to stop on first error?

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have a number of network requests and one or more of them will return valid data and is possible that some will return an error. How can I combine this request to stop once the first valid returned the data but not to stop in case of error.

I have try like this:

```
[[RACSignal merge:@[sigOne, sigTwo, sigThree]]
        subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *myData){
            NSLog(@"Data received");
        } error:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"E %@", error);
        }
        completed:^{
            NSLog(@"They're all done!");
        }
     ];
```

My problems:

- if one of the signals returns first with error then no next will be send. Not desired because one of the other signals will return valid data.
- if all three return valid data then the subscribeNext will be called three times but I would like to stop as soon I got some valid data (to reduce network traffic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[[[[RACSignal merge:@[[sigOne catchTo:[RACSignal empty]], 
                      [sigTwo catchTo:[RACSignal empty]], 
                      [sigThree catchTo:[RACSignal empty]]]] 
                          repeat] take:1]
    subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *myData){
        NSLog(@"Data received");
    } error:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"E %@", error);
    }
    completed:^{
        NSLog(@"They're all done!");
    }
 ];
```

By using `catchTo:`, the signals are being replaced with an empty signal when they error, which just causes the signal to send `complete`, and doesn't end the subscription for every other signal.
By adding repeat, we're getting the signal to run again if no `next` events occurred (because all of the signals errored).
By adding `take:1`, the signal will complete once a single `next` event is received.

Comment: thank you mate! this is what i was looking for. Is there a way to complete the merge signal if all the signals returned error?

Comment: Yup, that's easy, just remove the repeat method.